# Adding INSERT statement inside the CASE WHEN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Code:

```
   'Status' = 
       CASE  
           WHEN @ID = 2 AND Stud.Status = 'N' THEN 'To Be Submitted'
           WHEN Stud.Status = 'N' THEN 'N/A' 
           ELSE ISNULL(Stud.Status, '') 
        END
```

I want to add an `Insert` statement if the first condition is satisfied, That is, after the following code. How to add an `Insert` statement here.

```
WHEN @ID = 2 AND Stud.Status = 'N' THEN 'To Be Submitted'
```

Thanks.

Comment: im puzzled on how can you add case result to a string?

Comment: @GustavKlimt - It's just a way of assigning an alias/column name.

Comment: @MitchWheat: but `'Status'` is a string *literal*, not an identifier.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - What the OP is doing with `'Status' = ...` *does work* in SQL Server to create an alias/column name.

Comment: @Nicarus: I don't get it. `'Status'` is a *string literal* because of the single quotes. How can it be a column name?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SQL Server allows this. It is no different than: `MyColumn 'MyAlias'` or `MyColumn AS 'MyAlias'`. I don't know what else to tell you other than SQL Server supports this and I have seen multiple SQL scripters use this.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO [DestinationTable]
SELECT
    [MyColumn1]
FROM
    [SourceTable]
WHERE
    @ID = 2 AND
    Stud.Status = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make your query into a Store Procedure, add your first query to a [temp table](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html) and then split it into what you need... for example:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(50), Status NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT Name, 
   CASE  
       WHEN @ID = 2 AND Stud.Status = 'N' THEN 'To Be Submitted'
       WHEN Stud.Status = 'N' THEN 'N/A' 
       ELSE ISNULL(Stud.Status, '') 
    END as Status
FROM [Table]
WHERE [column] = 'value';
```

and then use that temp table to perform your insert

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable]
SELECT TOP 1 Name, Status 
FROM @TempTable
WHERE Status = 'To Be Submitted';
```

This way you are only inserting what you need as

> I want to add an Insert statement if the first condition is satisfied

`TOP 1` will make sure of that

Comment: maybe... I'm still trying to figure it out what he wants after all :)