# Insert statement inside CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server

How do I use the INSERT statement inside a CASE WHEN statement?

Here's a sample code:

```
    select case when SOME_CONDITION then 
    (insert into TABLE2(column1,column2) select * from TABLE1 end)
    from TABLE1
```

Comment: This isn't valid syntax, as you've probably noticed. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to insert just the rows that adhere to the condition into `table2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding INSERT statement inside the CASE WHEN condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134977/adding-insert-statement-inside-the-case-when-condition)

Comment: @Mureinik Yes. I'm trying to add rows that when that condition is matched

Comment: It's a case *expression*, not *statement*. The difference is an expression returns an atomic value, which is why you can't use it the way you attempt to.

Comment: @HoneyBadger any suggestions then?

Comment: Follow Tim Biegeleisen's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the restriction logic to the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (column1, column2)
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE <some condition>;
```

Depending on the logic of the `WHERE` clause, only certain records would be targeted for insertion.

Comment: @inadvisableguy Well give us the logic and we can write the query.  Anyway, I believe that my answer fixes the structural problems you were having.

Answer (score 0):

Your base statement is to insert into a table selecting from other table 
base on a case select statement if i did understand your question !

you can try to manipulate it using this query even if i'm not realy fan of it

try to understand what you need to do and retourn it into an SQL language addaptable

the bigest work is to understand what you want and turn it to an SQL statement that SQL server understand

```
with CTP as (select * 
             from table1 
             where <'the condition that you want on the case statement'>
            )

    insert into TABLE2(column1,column2)
        select column1,column2 
        from table1
        where id in (select id from CTP)
```